# Protractor installation fails due to Network connectivity issue

Tags: node.js, protractor

I am using Corporate Laptop and I tried to install Protractor to it,I am getting the below error message [This is what the command prompt says](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rRAnb.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error says: *This is most likely **not a problem with npm itself**... In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings*.  Ask your dev ops guys or network admins.

Comment: Thank you for response.Is there any self set up help so that I can configure by myself or Are I need the help of admins to resolve it?